# Stack Navigation on same screen multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

**Current Behavior**

What code are you running and what is happening?

Lets say I have 2 screens [A, B], and B is on top of stack currently.
Now, I have to open another instance of screen B, with different data and parameters, so that stack looks like [A, B, B]. For this, I have used navigation.push()
What is happening is that when I go Back from second B to first B, the first B does not load with its previous data, rather with the new data and parameters again.

**Expected Behavior**

If I am pushing another instance of same component, say B, into the stack, with different data, then ideally both the instances of B should hold their respective props and data, like two seperate screens, and when I navigate back, the previous screen should load as it is. Somewhat like [A, B1, B2]. It should not behave like Both B instances are now pointing to the same props and data!!
So technically when I am going from B2 to B1, it displays the data of B2 only rather than B1, which is a buggy situation altogether!!!!

Any kind of sensible help would be deeply appreciated!!!!!

react-navigation : 3.11.1
react-native : 0.60.5

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @VarunJoshi Yes, I found it, this can be done by the concept of dynamic reducers, if you are using redux. The idea is to create dynamic redux states ad store values for each screen instance. You can refer here: [link] https://tylergaw.com/articles/dynamic-redux-reducers/

Comment: Super, thanks @ApoorvaVerma